# Конвертировать цвет

Tags: sql, color

Есть база данных **sql** которая хранит цвет в формате `int` например **15620996** после конверта, даже с помощью калькулятора для меня это розовый цвет...

чтобы использовать данное число как цвет конвертирую его различными способами

[вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703019/convert-integer-to-hex-and-hex-to-integer) нашла функцию

```
    DECLARE @digit char(1)
    SET @seq = '0123456789ABCDEF'

    SET @result = SUBSTRING(@seq, (@value%16)+1, 1)

    WHILE @value > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @digit = SUBSTRING(@seq, ((@value/16)%16)+1, 1)

        SET @value = @value/16
        IF @value <> 0 SET @result = @digit + @result
    END 

    RETURN @result
END
GO

SELECT dbo.ToHex(15620996)  ---> EE5B84 => что равно розовый
```

вот так тоже в самой процедуре

```
,(SELECT '#' + FORMAT(MyColorFromDB, 'X')  FROM MyTable WHERE someCondition) AS ColorTaskHex
```

это мне возвращает *розовый* цвет, но дело в том что это фиолетовый в программе, которая берет из базы данных этот цвет, программа написана на **WinDev**, и когда я взяла `picker` и маркером выделила цвет в самой программе, мне это выдало `rgb(132, 91, 238)` => `84, 5B, EE`, потом я ввела в **WinDev** `rvb(132,91,238)` и получила 15620996, то есть выходит сохранение данных верно, и мы сохраняем Фиолетовый, но как из этого `int` (полученного из rvb(?)) получить обратно нормальный цвет в формате **hex** или **rgb** ?

Я почитала в самой [документации](https://doc.pcsoft.fr/?3029012) , но что то не пойму как создать 'обратный' алгоритм.

Метку `WinDev` не нашла, и возможно мало кто с этим работал, но может есть идеи куда копать ?

я вот вижу 84, 5B, EE (фиолетовый из программы) и EE5B84 (розовый, который я получаю из int путем конвертирования) как будто он меняет первое и последнее значение ? или совпадение...

Comment: Есть два варианта записи, RRGGBB и BBGGRR, все верно угадали

Comment: @Kromster док если попадется, поделитесь пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переводите число `15620996` в шестнадцатиричную форму, получаете `0xEE5B84`. Вот вам ваши (84, 5B, EE), можете доставать любым удобным способом.

Вот так можно получить все три RGB-компоненты:

```
r = a // 256 // 256    # 238
g = (a // 256 ) % 256  # 91
b = a % 256            # 132
```

// - целочисленное деление, % - остаток от деления.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151600/discussion-on-answer-by---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

> @Kromster Есть два варианта записи, RRGGBB и BBGGRR (здесь нужен док)
>
> @Эникейщик Вы можете переставлять местами данные, выбрав из 16тиричной системы

*делая выводы, что int, который BGR, мы будем вручную выбирать из базы, меняя местами под наш конкретный запрос, итак:*

создаю функцию, и ставлю порядок BBGGRR

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetColor]
(
    @ColorValue INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RGBString VARCHAR(50)
    
   
    SET @RGBString = 'RGB(' 
+ CAST(@ColorValue % 256 AS VARCHAR) + ',' 
+ CAST((@ColorValue / 256) % 256 AS VARCHAR) + ','
+ CAST((@ColorValue / 256 / 256) % 256 AS VARCHAR)  + ')'
    
   
    RETURN @RGBString
END
```

вызываю в запросе

```
,dbo.GetColor(MyColor) AS ColorTaskHex
```

на выходе

`RGB(132,91,238)`